# Ocaml Thread misunderstanding

Tags: multithreading, ocaml

I only see the whole output after a 5 sec delay, but I think it should be otherwise.

I expect following output:

> main is here
>   hi received
>   (*and only then sleep for 5 sec*)

but my code starts by sleeping first for 5 sec and only then continues.

```
let t1 ch = 
    let m = sync (receive ch) in 
    print_string (m ^ " -> received\n");
    delay 5.0;
    sync (send ch "t1 got the message")

let main () = 
    let ch = new_channel () in 
    create t1 ch;
    print_string "main is here\n";
    sync (send ch "hi");
    print_string ("main confirms :" ^ sync(receive ch))
```

I would gladly read some tutorials online but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing the output

```
print_string "main is here\n";
flush stdout
```